# Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function

Tags: vue.js

Getting an infinite loop error when looping through `<a>` attributes in vue.js.
I have a method that loops through and adds attributes dynamically but when I use the method by binding it to an attribute in the `<a>` I get the error from the title. The attributes are a nested object within the original products array of objects.

Vue Code

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>
      <a
        v-for="product in products"
        :href="product.product_url"
        type="submit"
        v-bind:additionalAttrs="addAttributes()"
      >
        Click Me
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
data () {
    return {
      addedAttributes: [],
    };
  },
props: {
    products: Array,
  },
methods: {
    addAttributes() {
      this.products.forEach(product => {
          for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(product.attributes)) {
            this.addedAttributes.push(`${key}: ${value}`);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a method call to pass its result to `additionalAttrs` prop but it's not reactive and potentially can be called as many times as you have elements in `products` array

You just need one computed prop instead of an array and a method because they simply depend on `products` prop:

```html
<a
  v-for="product in products"
  :href="product.product_url"
  type="submit"
  v-bind:additionalAttrs="addedAttributes"
>
Click Me
</a>
```

```js
computed: {
  addedAttributes() {
      const addedAttributes = []
      this.products.forEach(product => {
          for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(product.attributes)) {
            addedAttributes.push(`${key}: ${value}`);
        }
      });
      return addedAttributes
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep this was the issue, good to know I can just use computed vs methods if I only depend on the props passed in.

Comment: And if you want it to be reactive